# How to detect panning on GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to plot some markers on my  Application using Google Maps.Initially the application displays some markers at around current location.Then after panning on map new markers have to be displayed on new camera position.This should be displayed after the user have stopped panning.Currently the markers are stored in remote database.After user have stopped panning markers have to be loaded by calling webservice.

The problem is that how can i detect the panning on map and when the panning have stopped.Google maps OnCameraChangeListener() cannot be implemented because it detects all changes on map including zoom change thru code also.I have to detect the pann change thru touching on map only because there is lot of  zoom and camera changes thru code also.

I followed the [github](https://github.com/MadsFrandsen/MapStateListener) link

Actually I am not getting the correct idea how to implement the MapStateListener in my map View activity.
and many other links in Stack Overflow but cannot get any solution while implementing.